# Selenium python-grid-DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,No route to host

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I started selenium hub on machine1 (ubuntu), start the node2 on machine2 (Redhat 6). Both machines have the same version of `selenium server=selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar`

Problem: when I run test, it gives me error:

> [EXCEPTION]  Message: Error forwarding the new session Error
>   forwarding the request No route to host Stacktrace:
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:114)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:83)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost (DriverServlet.java:67)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:727)

On the hub URL: http://10.1.19.123:4444/grid/console#
It shows my node2 has this string on the top=DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version, No route to host

But if I started a node on hub machine1. The test will run to this machine1 with no problem. Basically, if the node and hub are on the same machine, my test will run fine.
I googled and found the possible reason is communication between machine 1 and 2, but when I ping each other on machine1 and 2, they can ping each other with no problem. I am out of solution. Please help.